# Codeigniter db query clause where not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I built a query:

```
 public function getContacts($limit, $start, $search)
{

    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);

    if (!empty($search)) {
        $this->db->like('name', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('last_name', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('phone_number', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('created_at', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('note', $search);
    }



    $query = $this->db->get_where('contact', array('user_id' => 3));

    return $query->result_array();

}
```

but the where clause does not work. It should return only results with user_id equals to 3 but it returns everything.

What is wrong?

This is the query executed:

```
SELECT * FROM `contact` WHERE name LIKE '%stefano%' ESCAPE '!' OR last_name LIKE '%stefano%' ESCAPE '!' OR phone_number LIKE '%stefano%' ESCAPE '!' OR created_at LIKE '%stefano%' ESCAPE '!' OR note LIKE '%stefano%' ESCAPE '!' AND `user_id` = 3 LIMIT 2
```

Tried this query in Workbench and still ignoring the AND user_id = 3.
If my logic is not wrong it should return only rows where user_id = 3 but returns all.

Comment: what about adding `->where` above everything else

Comment: tried but does not work

Comment: which version are you using @StefanoMaglione

Comment: 3.1.8 is my version

Comment: strange, do `$this->db->where('user_id', 3); echo $this->db->get_compiled_select('contact');` and share the statement (remove everything include $query).

Comment: just before the return add `echo $this->db->last_query()` what is the output?

Comment: I added the result to the post. @FastSnail

Comment: This is unbelievable

Comment: this is because your `OR` condition matches other rows. for your desired result you may use parentheses and group `AND` `OR`

Comment: @RejoanulAlam yes you are right! Now the problem is how to do it with Codeigniter but definitely is this the reason!

Comment: @Ghost i too wonder if that would change anything. i doubt it as qb probably rearranges things when get() is called, but still, would be interesting to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add group_start() and group_end().like this.

```
 if (!empty($search)) {
      $this->db->group_start();
        $this->db->like('name', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('last_name', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('phone_number', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('created_at', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('note', $search);
        ->group_end();
    }
```

Comment: I tried to fix a syntax error you had but I guess you reverted it. You can only change group_end() if the previous doesn't have a semi colon (or so I thought).

Comment: *chain instead of change

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function getContacts($limit, $start, $search)
{
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('contact');
  if (!empty($search)) {
    $this->db->like('name', $search);
    $this->db->or_like('last_name', $search);
    $this->db->or_like('phone_number', $search);
    $this->db->or_like('created_at', $search);
    $this->db->or_like('note', $search);
  }

  $this->db->where(array('user_id' => 3));
  $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: how is separating the statements going to change anything? i don't remember reading anywhere in the docs get_where() can't be used with other methods (aside from where)... this is why it is usually a good idea to add some context to your answers

Comment: @Alex In fact `get_where()` is combination of `get()` & `where()`

Answer (score -2):

**Try this code:**

```
public function getContacts($limit, $start, $search)
{

    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);

    if (!empty($search)) {
        $this->db->select(*);
        $this->db->like('name', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('last_name', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('phone_number', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('created_at', $search);
        $this->db->or_like('note', $search);
    }



    $this->db->select(*);
    $this->db->where('user_id','3');
    $query = $this->db->get('tablename');
    return $query->result_array();

}
```